# Auto remove users reactions

Tags: discord.js, bots

Im using the code below. The code works but i want it so whenever the user reacts to it the emoji reactions resets whenever they react to it, if that even made sense.

Does anybody know the best way of doing this? or if there is something else I need to do instead?

````
if(message.embeds)
        {
            const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'Select the games that you play (you can choose multiple)');
            if(embedMsg)
            {
                message.react('746208061550624860')
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('746203917272219891'))
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('746207267728392232')
                .catch(err => console.error);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '?roles')
    {
        message.delete()
        if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle('Select the games that you play (you can choose multiple)')
        embed.setColor(colors.blue);
        embed.setDescription(
        "NOTE: When you select any of these you will have access to the community chat of the game\n"+
        "<:cod:746208061550624860> - COD\n" +
        "<:valoran:746203917272219891> - VALORAN\n" +
        "<:warframe:746208599021191190> - WARFRAME\n");
        message.channel.send(embed)
        
    } else {
        message.reply("You don't have permission to use this command.");
    }
    }
});

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.bot)
    return;

    var roleName = reaction.emoji.name;
    var role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase());
    var member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);

    if(member.roles.cache.has(role.id))
    {
        member.roles.remove(role.id).then(member => {
            console.log("Removed" + member.user.username + "from the" + role.name + "name.");
        }).catch(err => console.error);
    } 
    else {
        member.roles.add(role.id).then(member => {
            console.log('Added' + member.user.username + 'to the' + role.name + ' role.');
        }).catch(err => console.error);
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `remove()` method assuming you have `user` defined as the person who reacted
`reaction.users.remove(user);`

Answer (score 0):

```
message.reactions.cache.get('ur_role_id').remove().catch(error => console.error('Failed to remove reactions: ', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MessageReaction.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=remove):

```js
reaction.remove(user)
```

---

Also, you are overcomplicating this line:

```js
var member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
```

Instead, you can use the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) function:

```js
var member = reaction.message.guild.member(user);
```